# Jquery preventDefault removung

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

This is my Jquery code

```
     <script>

       $(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#target").submit(function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

   $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/account/check_user_access',function(data){

     if(data=='true'){

     }

     else{
      alert("You are not authorized");
      $('body').html(data);
     }

    });
        })

   })

</script>
```

Now when data of post function return true I want to remove the preventDefault.How can I do It?

Comment: Try to add `$("#target")[0].submit();` in the `if` block, so that the form is submitted

Comment: @Adil you can't because it is in an ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#target").submit(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/account/check_user_access', function (data) {
             if (data == 'true') {
                 //trigger a programatic form submission which will not trigger the submit event handler
                 $("#target")[0].submit();
             } else {
                 alert("You are not authorized");
                 $('body').html(data);
             }

         });
     })

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the preventDefault using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) with [namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $("#target").on('submit.something',function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

   $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/account/check_user_access',function(data){

     if(data=='true'){
        //now unbind the submit 
       $(this).off('.something');
     }

     else{
      alert("You are not authorized");
      $('body').html(data);
     }

    });
        })

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In this method, your Ajax call waits for a response before any logic is handled. If your request fails, or is unsuccessful, your mouse click capture will be prevented.

```
$(document).ready(function () {       

   $("#target").submit(function (e) {

      $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/account/check_user_access', function (data) {

         if (data === "true"){

            $("#target")[0].submit();

         } else {

            e.preventDefault();
            alert("You are not authorized");
            $('body').html(data);

         };

      });
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that as you have an asynchronous Ajax request involved. But you can add this in the if statement to submit the form:

```
this.submit();
```

Comment: you mean $(this).submit().

Comment: No.  I mean what I have written.